# How to download numpy array files from an online drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, onedrive

I have a dataset contains hundreds of numpy arrays looks like this,

[image]

I am trying to save them to an online drive so that I can run the code with this dataset remotely from a sever. I cannot access the drive of the server but can only run code script and access the terminal. So I have tried with google drive and Onedrive, and looked up how to generate a direct download link from those drives but it did not work.

In short, I need to be able to get those files from my python scripts. Could anyone give some hints?

Comment: Hi there @JINGYAHAN! I have some doubts about your question. I understand that you want to set up a Drive script in Python to download files from your Drive account. Is that accurate?

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron Yes, I am not sure if google drive or one drive is right choice though, since I cannot get a direct download link from those drives.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the download URLs very easily from Drive. I assume that you already uploaded the files into a Drive folder. Then you can easily set up a scenario to download the files on Python. First you would need an environment on Python to connect to Drive. If you don't currently have one, you can follow this [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python). That guide will install the required libraries, credentials and run a sample script. Once you can run the sample script you can make minor modifications to reach your goal.

To download the files you are going to need their ids. I am assuming that you already know them, but if you don't you could retrieve them by doing a [`Files.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) on the folder where you keep the files. To do so you can use `'{ FOLDER ID }' in parents` as the `q` parameter.

To download the files you only have to run a [`Files.get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) request by providing the file id. You will find the download URL on the `webContentLink` property. Feel free to leave a comment if you need further clarifications.